# Vector notation in Word equation editor comes up as "r" on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, equations, equation-editor, microsoft-word-2008

I am using Word 2008 on Mac OS X and find that whenever I try to make denote a letter as a vector variable (with an arrow pointing to the right on top of the letter) using Equation Editor, the letter appears with the letter "r" on top of it -- instead of the arrow.

I am using Mac OS X version 10.6.3.  Other aspects of Equation Editor seem to be working.  Any idea how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a guess. Perhaps you don't have a needed font installed or there is a font substitution. This [article](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3686264.php) suggests that the only font that provides the needed symbols is Cambria Math. I certainly cannot change the font to anything else in Word 2007 for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Wayne is partially correct, but Cambria Math isn't needed in Word 2008 and probably isn't available anyway. The font you're missing is MT Extra. Sometimes this happens if Word is installed after MathType, or if an update to Word reinstalls the MT Extra font. Reinstalling MathType will probably correct the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the right font. I thought it might be different for a Mac when I answered the question. - Wayne